# How to mock a ScriptMethod of PSCustomObject from another script?

Tags: powershell, automated-tests, pester

We are trying to figure out how to mock a ScriptMethod of PSCustomObject from another script using Pester.

**Script1.ps1**

```
$script2    = & $Script2PS1Path -programName $myScriptName

function Invoke-MyFunction {

$script2.outHost("test data")

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $path -Filter "ABC_*"
...
...
}
```

**Script2.ps1**

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$False,HelpMessage="Mandatory.")]
    [string]$programName
)

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

$obj = New-Object PSCustomObject
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name prog               -Value $programName
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -name outHost -Value {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        $text,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [string]$foregroundcolor,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [string]$backgroundcolor
    )

    if ($foregroundcolor -and $backgroundcolor) {
        Write-Host -Foregroundcolor $foregroundcolor -Backgroundcolor $backgroundcolor $text
    } elseif ($foregroundcolor) {
        Write-Host -Foregroundcolor $foregroundcolor $text
    } elseif ($backgroundcolor) {
        Write-Host -Backgroundcolor $backgroundcolor $text
    } else {
        Write-Host $text
    }
}

$obj

exit(0)
```

In the example above we need to mock `$script2.outHost` to test `Invoke-MyFunction`. What is the best way to mock `$script2.outHost` ?

Comment: `Add-Member -Force -MemberType ScriptMethod -name outHost -Value { }` lets you override the existing script method.

Comment: Where does outHost  must be overridden? Is it from the test ? Is there any way to mock $script2 and its methods using pester?

Comment: Pester is only able to mock commands. E. g. you could mock `Write-Host`. This should work for `outHost` method. In the general case you may have to wrap method calls into cmdlets, to make them mockable.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you invoke this in your tests + that this is really scripts and not modules (adds some complexity).

If `Script1.ps1` is dot-sourced in a `BeforeAll`-block and you run `Invoke-MyFunction` in the It-block, then simply override the ScriptMethod as mentioned in the comments, ex.

```
It 'myTest' {
    $script2 | Add-Member -Force -MemberType ScriptMethod -name outHost -Value { 'mocked behavior' }`
    Invoke-MyFunction
}
```

If `Script1.ps1` really invokes `Invoke-MyFunction` inside the script, so your test only execute `& Script1.ps1`, then you'd have to mock `Add-Member` and target the right call using `-ParameterFilter`. Ex:

Script1.ps1

```
# Temp variables to make sample complete
# Script2.ps1 from OP is placed in the same folder
$Script2PS1Path = "$PSScriptRoot\Script2.ps1"
$myScriptName = 'demo'

$script2 = & $Script2PS1Path -programName $myScriptName

function Invoke-MyFunction {
    $script2.outHost('test data')
}

# Added to complete sample
Invoke-MyFunction
```

Script1.tests.ps1

```
Describe 'Script1' {
    It 'mockoutHost' {
        # Create mock for Add-Member targeted for the outHost-call
        Mock -CommandName Add-Member -ParameterFilter { $MemberType -eq 'ScriptMethod' -and $Name -eq 'outHost' } -MockWith {
            # Get real Add-Member
            $cmd = (Get-Command -Name Add-Member -CommandType Cmdlet)

            # Override incoming Value (ScriptMethod-codeblock)
            # $PesterBoundParameters requires Pester 5.2+
            $PesterBoundParameters['Value'] = { Write-Warning "I got mocked at $((Get-Date).ToString('o'))" }

            # Call real Add-Member with modified ScriptMethod
            & $cmd @PesterBoundParameters
        }

        # Invoke Script1.ps1
        & "$PSScriptRoot\Script1.ps1"
        # Profit
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Starting discovery in 1 files.
Discovery found 1 tests in 24ms.
Running tests.
WARNING: I got mocked at 2022-08-03T21:57:04.4306325+00:00
[+] /workspaces/Pester/Samples/MockScriptMethod/Script1.Tests.ps1 100ms (52ms|25ms)
Tests completed in 101ms
Tests Passed: 1, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 0
```